# The general idea behind proving the triangle inequality of the essential supremum norm.(Royden 4th edition on pg.138)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

The proof is given below:

> [image]

But I do not understand the role of $E_{n}$ in the proof and how to create it. what criteria we are looking for in it? and why we create it?

Could anyone explains this for me, please?

Comment: How is $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ defined?

Comment: @grndl it is the infimum of the essential upper bounds for $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $||f||_{\infty}$ is the infimum of all essential upper bounds.

In the first part it is shown that this infimum is attained and, hence, is a minimum.

This is then helpful and (a bit implicitly) used to show that the sum of two essentially bounded functions is also essentially bounded. Or in other words: $f,g \in L^{\infty}(E)\Rightarrow f+g \in L^{\infty}(E)$.

To show that the infimum is attained it is necessary to show that there is a measurable subset $N \subset E$ with $|f(x)|\leq ||f||_{\infty}$ on $E\setminus N$ such that $m(N)= 0$.

Since $||f||_{\infty}$ is the infimum of all essential upper bounds, the author now approaches $||f||_{\infty}$ from above by invoking that $||f||_{\infty}+\frac 1n$ is an essential upper bound, hence, there are for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ measurable subsets $E_n$ with $m(E_n) = 0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq ||f||_{\infty}+\frac 1n$ on $E\setminus E_n$.

Now, if $x \in E \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ this means that $|f(x)| \leq ||f||_{\infty}+\frac 1n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which is equivalent with $|f(x)| \leq ||f||_{\infty}$.

Since $E_{\infty}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ is the at most countable union of sets of measure zero, we know that $m(E_{\infty}) = 0$. So, $||f||_{\infty}$ is the **least** essential upper bound.

Comment: does infimum of all essential upper bounds means least upper bound?

Comment: So the main complexity in this proof is showing that the sum of 2 essentially bounded functions is also essentialy bounded .... correct?

Comment: O do not understand your fourth paragraph at all. why to show that the infimum is attained I have to show that? there is no definition of infimum in the book tha said we have to show this.

Comment: The important fact here is that the minimum of all essential bounds is an essential bound itself. Without this fact, just try to prove the triangle inequality only using the definition of the infimum. you will realize that the proof would become more technical and inelegant.